# Python for loop - stripping line as you go

Tags: python, for-loop, strip

I am trying to strip a line of code so that only the comment at the end is saved. Because `#` signs can be included within `""` marks, to do this I am trying to cycle through the line catching pairs of `"` marks so that it ignores any `#` marks within `""` marks. When I use a code visualiser on my code below, after the second for loop it seems to go pack to processing `s` as if it has just stripped the first `"` mark. I can't see what I'm doing wrong here, because the print statement I have included on line 19 shows that `s` has been stripped to after the second `"`, but when the code returns to the top, it starts cycling again from after the first `"`. Any idea of what I am doing wrong here?

```
s = '("8# " + str" #9 " + line) #lots of hash(#) symbols here'
quoteCount = 0

for char in s:
    if quoteCount%2 == 0:
        if char == '#':
            s = s[s.index('#'):]
            break

    if char == '"':
        quoteCount = quoteCount + 1
        s = s[s.index('"'):]
        s = s.lstrip('"')
        for char in s:
            if char == '"':
                quoteCount = quoteCount + 1
                s = s[s.index('"'):]
                s = s.lstrip('"')
                print(s)
                break

print(s)
```

Comment: Can you please check if the code as it appears here looks exactly the same as in your IDE or text editor? The problem might be with the indentation of some lines, which is crucial in Python.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly you only want to keep the last comment (#lots of hash(#) symbols here).
To do this you don't need the nested for loop.

```
s = '("8# " + str" #9 " + line) #lots of hash(#) symbols here'

quoteCount = 0

for char in s:
    if quoteCount%2 == 0:
        if char == '#':
            s = s[s.index('#'):]
            break

    if char == '"':
        quoteCount = quoteCount + 1
        s = s[s.index('"'):]
        s = s.lstrip('"')

print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier to remove the quoted strings with a regular expression:

```
import re
s = '("8# " + str" #9 " + line) #lots of hash(#) symbols here'
pattern = r'"[^"]*"'
s = re.sub(pattern, '', s)
print s[s.index('#'):]
```

Output:

```
#lots of hash(#) symbols here
```

Comment: Explanation: This removes everything inside quotes from `s` and then takes everything from the first remaining `#` to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is overly complicated so I suggest you use an alternative method to finding the comment like the already mentioned regex one or the one I came up with.

```
s = '("8# " + str" #9 " + line) #lots of hash(#) symbols here'
s = s[s.rfind('"') + 1:]  # Get to the last quotation mark

if s.find('#') >= 0:  # The first # sign should start the comment if there is one
    s = s[s.find('#'):]

else:
    s = ''  # No comment was found

print(s)
```